# Timestamps in Windows are messed up

Tags: windows, video, timestamp, pictures

[I originally posted this in Stack Exchange Photography, but I was informed that it was off-topic, so I'm posting it in SuperUser. I sincerely apologize.]

Hello all,

I am on vacation in a time zone 15 hours ahead of home.

I was about to delete some old videos (from previous events near home) off my GoPro's SD card to make more space, when I decided to check once more to make sure that everything was copied to my hard drive. And gasp, a bunch of videos are missing... oh wait. No, I sort GoPro videos by date (those of you who have GoPros know why), and the timestamps of the videos on my hard drive are just completely off. Hence, when comparing date to date, it doesn't match up.

After checking around, I found out that this is expected behavior because NTFS records filestamps in UTC, and displays them in my current local UTC offset. ([Microsoft Support Page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/129574/time-stamp-changes-with-daylight-savings))

Yay... everything is messed up. But it gets even worse. And I found nothing written about this on the Internet. They aren't consistently off. I understand that timestamps on my GoPro's SD card will remain absolute (original time in the UTC offset at the time it was taken) because exFAT doesn't have such nonsense. But that's not all - it's inconsistent right on my hard drive.

Let me explain. All my videos are displayed in my local (vacation) UTC offset, but my pictures remain in my home (original) UTC offset. So the pictures are correct, but the videos display 15 hours ahead. Why is this? And what can I do about it? Might it have something to do with the fact that videos use date modified and pictures use date taken?

For testing purposes, I changed my computer's clock to home time zone. The timestamps of videos from before returned to normal. But the problem is now in reverse. The videos I took on vacation now display in home UTC offset, while the pictures retain their original UTC offset. So now the pictures are still correct, but now the videos are 15 hours behind.

I know that timestamps can be changed. I use ExifPro to change timestamps for pictures, and Advanced Renamer for videos. But I'll travelling through different time zones. And that will create a huge mess, one that's too complicated and tedious to fix manually.

Oh, one other thing I should point out; it may or may not be helpful. I use FreeFileSync to automatically copy files to my backup drive. They have a [help page](https://www.freefilesync.org/manual.php?topic=daylight-saving-time) explaining something like this but I'm not sure what they're talking about.

Can anyone help me figure this out? Thanks.

EDIT: I've returned home, and I've had a chance to look at my archived backups of pictures and videos taken when travelling to other time zones. The problem is there. Everywhere. So I don't think it has anything to do with FreeFileSync because that was from before I used it.

Funny I never noticed this before. But it really bugs me now. Now realizing that everything ever is wrong, I don't think I'm going to bother to try to fix it. But why? And why does no one else seem to expierence this? It seems like it could be very problematic in situations other than people just being perfectionistic.